# Plugin not working in Google Chrome for automation anywhere

Tags: rpa, automationanywhere

I have installed automation anywhere Plugin and developer mode also on mode in chrome but not working when I suppose to record a task getting error.

[image]

Comment: And not to make it too easy for anyone to solve, you decided not to include the error you get?

Comment: find the attachment of error kindly help to resolve problem. I have plug in AA in chrome,Developer mode is also on and also device connected in control room everything is good but unable to capture from Google chrome

Answer (score 1):

Please check if you can see Automation Anywhere Logo on the top right corner in Google Chrome. This indicates that the plug-in is installed successfully. If you are not able to see the Icon. Please follow the below steps.

**1. AA CLIENT :**

1.1. Plugin Settings

1.2. Go to Chrome and click on Open Folder

1.3. Find a file of name *"ChromeExtension.crx"*

**2. GOOGLE CHROME:**

2.1. Click on the 3 dots button then More tools then Extensions.

2.2. On the upper right corner, click on Enable Developer Mode.

2.3. Drag and drop the *"ChromeExtension.crx"* on Extensions page then Add Extension.

If the issue still persists, please Uninstall Google Chrome and try the above steps again.